# How do I create a user for Wordpress to do FTP stuff with, and give it proper permissions?

Tags: linux, wordpress, ubuntu, permissions, ftp

I am setting up wordpress on my Ubuntu server.
To install a wordpress theme, I need to provide wordpress with an FTP account that it can use to download the theme files.

I tried my usual FTP user and it is saying "cannot create directory ...."

How do I create an FTP user that wordpress can use to install themes and give it the proper permissions it needs to do so?

Running VSFTPD on Ubunu 12.04 with Webmin

Thanks

Comment: you'll need to create an account in vsftpd, then provide those details to wordpress when asked

Comment: Check out this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/14372/248282

Answer (score 1):

First create an FTP user, the set them to the WordPress group. The FTP user must have access permission to your upload, tmp, and template folders.